# updating pymode repository error: server does not allow request

Tags: python-mode

I run the following command:

```
 git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I got

```
error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object 837ecd3d7a8597ab5f28bc83072de68e16470f1e
Fetched in submodule path 'submodules/pylama', but it did not contain 837ecd3d7a8597ab5f28bc83072de68e16470f1e. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i sovled the problem by deleting the old pymode and reinstall that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the plugin folder (for me it is ~/.vim/bundle/python-mode), then go to the problem plugin folder and sync the submodules (between git config and .gitmodules):

```
cd submodules/pylama
git submodule sync
```

After this you should be able to update python mode as usual.

Comment: there is still error for pymode when I run PluginUpdate in vundle after doing what you suggested

Comment: : [2019-01-11 11:53:13] > error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object 837ecd3d7a8597ab5f28bc83072de68e16470f1e

Comment: That is weird. You may try going with 'git submodule update --init --force --recursive' from the same 'pylama' dir